# What is an "integer<H>"? (TypeError: argument must be integer<H>, not int)

Tags: python, autopy

I am trying to use a function from [autopy](http://www.autopy.org/documentation/api-reference/key.html) and get the error message

```
TypeError: argument must be integer<H>, not int
```

What does this "integer<H>" mean?

My code:

```
import autopy, os, time
from autopy import key
time.sleep(1)
key.tap(key.K_RETURN)
```

Comment: Seems to work for me in Idle on Windows. Maybe the installation was faulty?

Comment: Also key._K_RETURN is and should be a normal int.

Comment: https://github.com/msanders/autopy/issues/67

Comment: casting the key.K_RETURN to long() was successful, I'll try it that way thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that autopy was not happy with the type of the passed key and that that type was `int`. What type it expected instead is (at least to me) completely unclear from the error message. `integer<H>` doesn't really mean anything in Python, AFAIK, so that doesn't make a lot of sense. Maybe this library has its own notation for type constraints.

A [comment on the autopy issue tracker](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/issues/67#issuecomment-84649176) mentions

```
key.toggle(long(key.K_DELETE), True)
```

as a workaround, which indicates that (in some situations, probably specific to operating system and/or Python version) the expected type is `long`. Applied to your code, that'd be

```
key.tap(long(key.K_RETURN))
```

Comment: Oh, I see that while I typed this in, you already arrived at the same conclusion in the comments. :-)